# How to Upgrade from OpenSSL 0.9.8e to openssl-1.0.0e

Tags: openssl

**EDIT** When I check the version in Putty "openssl version" it says Im using the new version but php is still showing the old?

I did the following with Putty and it looked like it worked but I am still seeing the old version when I view my phpinfo() file.

I am failing the PCI test and really need to get this fixed.

Do I need to delete the old version first? Is that safe?

```
Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 
mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.3.8
```

putty commands

```
* cd /usr/local/src
* wget -N http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz
* tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.0c.tar.gz 
* cd openssl-1.0.0c
* ./config
* make
* make install
* alias cp=cp
* cp /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
* cd /usr/local/ssl/include
* ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl openssl
```

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: @ErikA I did using cpanel whm, Still shows the same old version

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Linux distribution are you running on?

Comment: @Rilindo WHM 11.30.3 (build 5)
CENTOS 5.6 i686 standard on ip-208-109-104-23

Comment: Which part of the PCI test are you failing? Be specific.

Comment: Says my version of openssl is out of date. Had some other version issues to but I think I fixed them.

Comment: Okay, then you just upgrade to the latest openssl version provided by CentOS Red Hat (which Centos is based on), back ports the security updates, and increment just the sub-version number. If you do that, there is would not be any need to compile a specific version of OpenSSL.

Comment: @Rilindo  Was that in spanish :)

Comment: @Rilindo im pretty sure the update is installed. Just not showing correctly in my php file

Comment: No, my point is that there is no need for you to build a version of openssl to begin with. As long as RedHat/CentOS back ports the updates, you just upgrade with their updated packages and you are done. If you are failing PCI Compliance because of a version number, then the problem is with the process, not with the package.

Comment: @Rilindo Im new to this but when I upgraded using the easyapache updater it installed an old version. But, I do want to that you. You have been a lot of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Ignacio's post:

http://blog.800hosting.com/tag/centos-redhat-rpm-pci-compliance/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837145/pci-compliance-magento-php-version

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the PCI compliance test is... naive, and only checks the version number. You need to find out which specific vulnerabilities it's looking for and then check the OpenSSL package changelog (`rpm --changelog openssl`) to verify that yes, those vulnerabilities have been patched.